# How to get VMs that are part of a Reservation in Azure with Kusto/KQL

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

Is it possible to extract which VMs you have in the Reservation service in Azure portal with a KQL ?

We would like to extract this data into a PowerBI report to have an overview of which VM is linked to what Reservation in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get VMs that are part of a Reservation in Azure with Kusto/KQL

Here is the `Query` to check `Azure Virtual Machines` that are part of `Reservation`.

```
    resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
    | where properties.extended.instanceView.reservationId != ""
    | project name, properties.extended.instanceView.reservationId
```

> Note: Since I don't have any **Virtual Machines** that are part of a reservation, it's showing no results in my case.

[image]

Reference: [VMs included in all reservations - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185135/vms-included-in-all-reservations) by @ vipullag-MSFT

Comment: Thank you for your reply Venkat! It seems like we are missing the "reservation.id" under properties.extended.instanceView though... do you think this can be because of some access rights in Azure?

Comment: Yes, you need to have Owner or Reservation Purchaser permissions on the subscription. Check this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=867775